# Want to create a frame taking mouse input and implements drawLines()

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create a frame that is taking input from mouse and also make x/o grid on frame using `drawLines()`. But I am able to do only one of the two.

Here is my code:

```
public class Test extends JPanel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Test t = new Test();  
        t.dispFrame();

    }

    public static void dispFrame()
     {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("My New Frame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));

        frame.setResizable(false);

         JPanel panel=new JPanel();
         panel.addMouseListener(new MouseListener()
         {                         
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println(":MOUSE_CLICK_EVENT:");
            }

             @Override
             public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                 System.out.println("\n:MOUSE_PRESSED_EVENT:");
             }

             @Override
             public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                 System.out.println(":MOUSE_RELEASED_EVENT:");
             }

             @Override
             public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                 System.out.println(":MOUSE_ENTER_EVENT:");
             }

             @Override
             public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                 System.out.println(":MOUSE_EXITED_EVENT:");
             }

         });
         frame.add(panel);
         frame.pack();
         frame.setVisible(true);
     }

      @Override
      public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
      {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawLine(30,100,270,100);
        g.drawLine(30,200,270,200);
        g.drawLine(100,35,100,250);
        g.drawLine(200,35,200,250);   
      }
}
```

Comment: Start by talking a look at [How to perform custom painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Comment: Maybe something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30882447/i-added-a-rectangle-to-a-shape-arraylist-but-the-shape-will-not-show-up-on-the-p/30882512#30882512) will help

Comment: The whole design is incorrect. For the example it would be better to extend the JFrame not the JPanel. Anyway it wouldn't be with a paintComponent. Unfortunately I cannot write a sample right now, but you should take a look at the swing tutorial (originally by Sun) that you can find in Oracle's website

Comment: @prmottajr Actually, the design is moving in the right direction, extending from JFrame looks you into a single use case and besides, your not really extending the functionality of the frame it self. You should also avoid overriding paint of top level containers as they aren't double buffered and their child components can be painted independently with the frames paint method been called, leading to no end of weirdness. Putting the custom painting into something like JPanel is a better solution

Comment: @MadProgrammer humm ok, you got a point there. I was thinking more in the sense of a simple example. But if the idea is to create a new (game board) component that is able to draw itself adding the MouseListener as an anonimous inner class would be of poor readability. I think that it will depend on the goal, I would prefer a Board that could extend JPanel and a separate MouseListener that would be added during game creation, but this off the way of the question I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to override the `paintComponent()` method on your panel, you should do something like this,

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
  @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawLine(30,100,270,100);
    g.drawLine(30,200,270,200);
    g.drawLine(100,35,100,250);
    g.drawLine(200,35,200,250);   
  }
};
```

In your code, your are overriding the `paintComponent()` in your `Test` class, which will throw a compile time error if your `Test` class itself is not a subclass `Component`.

Comment: JFrame doesn't have a paintComponent method and you shouldn't be overriding paint of top level containers anyway

Comment: JPanel doesn't have constructor which takes String